# Remove a Commit from a PR in Git

Tags: git

I created a PR but accidentally branched off the wrong commit.

```
commit 4
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1 <-- Want to get rid of first commit
```

`Commit 1` is actually part of another PR. I want to get rid of the first commit because it has nothing to do with the PR i created. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest, don’t-really-have-to-think-about-it way is usually an interactive rebase. Do `git rebase -i <pr-base>` (long: `git rebase --interactive <pr-base>`), delete the first line, save and quit. That’ll rewrite commit 1 out of history. Then it’s probably `git push --force-with-lease` as usual to sync the changes in your case.

Comment: whoa nice I didn't realize I could just do that! What's the difference between doing a --force and a --force-with-lease?

Comment: @lost9123193: `--force` always overwrites, but `--force-with-lease` checks that you know what you’re overwriting first, i.e. that your copy of the upstream still points to the same revision as the branch on the remote. (In other words, that what `git status` is telling you about how your local branch has diverged is still up to date.) It can be freely substituted in many cases and is the safer option.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the commit like it never was there i.e. the changes will be undone and it will be removed from history for that branch. Logically this will not work if newer commits are based on changes in the commit you want to remove. (Git will tell you about this "conflict".)

On the branch of your pull request:

1. `git rebase HEAD~4 --interactive` (4 is the number of commits to show)
2. change the first word from `pick` to `drop` for the commit you want to remove. [Warning: Risk of data loss. Make sure this commit is part of another branch if you do not want to lose its content.]
3. Save and close the "file".
4. `git push --force` (This will forcefully overwrite the remote. Imo that is no problem if you do not expect anyone else working on this remote branch.)

(Well it looks like I was too slow.)

Comment: when I drop it and do gitlog --oneline i still see the commit i tried to drop. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it should be gone and the changes of it should be undone. You need so save and close the file that git rebase opened.